# Debug a Node.js CLI tool with WebStorm; How?

Tags: typescript, debugging, webstorm

I'm trying to create a CLI tool using TypeScript, and using WebStorm as my IDE. Try as I might, I cannot seem to get the debugging function to work. I started my Node.js adventures in CLI programming based on this [tutorial](https://medium.com/geekculture/building-a-node-js-cli-with-typescript-packaged-and-distributed-via-homebrew-15ba2fadcb81). I am able to transpile the TS source by running `npx tsc`, and I'm able to run the resulting JS file from the CLI. I'm also able to run it from a Run Configuration in WebStorm. What I *can't* do is debug. I've tried setting breakpoints and running it as a Debug configuration. I've tried running it with the `--inspect-brk` option and a separate "Attach to Node.js/Chrome" configuration (all network addresses and ports look kosher). I've gotten it to say "Debugger attached." But it just never stops at any breakpoints in the IDE. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure to enable sourcemaps generation when compiling Typescript to JavaScript to be able to debug your code. To get them created, add `"sourceMap": true` to your `tsconfig.json`

See  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-and-debugging-typescript.html for more info

Comment: Thanks! I am accepting your answer, although I confess that the minute I got past this I ran into the fact that I don't have a bundler for this, so everything like import/requires of images failed. :facepalm: Oh well. Thanks again! One step closer...